# Catch-all controller, MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I am currently working on a MVC 5 project which will have several controllers and one of them (InformationController) is just performing the same operations on all actions, i.e.:

```
public ActionResult ActionName()
{
    LayoutModel Model = new LayoutModel();
    return View(Model);
}
```

Is it possible to catch all actions in one **generic** action? In that way it would be possible to add new views without recompiling. To say it again the model passed will always be a `LayoutModel` and there will never be any parameters.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to intercept all actions to perform some kind of pre-action operation, or you just want an application with only one action?  If the latter, how are your users even requesting other routes if there's only one action, one view, and no links to anything else?

Comment: I think I have a clue which way you are going, but you need to explain more to make us understand what you exactly want to achieve with it.

Comment: Yeah, all calls to urlto.website.com/Information/ANYTHING should map to corresponding view and pass a `LayoutModel`. I think DavidG got it correct below. Have not tested it yet though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work for you. Create a new route so that the action isn't required for that controller but instead passes in the view name:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "InformationControllerSharedAction",
    url: "Information/{actionType}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Information", action = "Index" }
);
```

Then using your Index action, you are now essentially passing in the view you want to render with:

```
public ActionResult Index(string actionType)
{
    LayoutModel Model = new LayoutModel();
    return View(actionType, model);
}
```

This will allow URLs like:

```
www.website.com/Information/View1
www.website.com/Information/View2
etc.
```

And all you need to do is to drop the views (`View1.cshtml`, `View2.cshtml`, etc.) into the right folder.

Comment: It worked. However I made some changes. This since if you use `@Url.Action("Index", "Information")` as a link on a sub-page, e.g. `www.website.com/Information/View1` the link will point to `www.website.com/Information/View1` since you have not explicitly set `actionType` to `Index`. I changed the route defaults to `defaults: new { controller = "Information", action = "Forward", actionType = "Index" }` and the action name to Forward. You then need to avoid using Forward as sub-page. This can also be fixed by explicitly adding  `new { actionType = "index" }` on all `@Url.Action`.

Answer (score 0):

register Routes in **Global.asax** (add routes in App_Start/RouteConfig.cs) for all the action to redirect to genric action

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Test",
    url: "{Home}/{test}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Genric", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Test1",
    url: "{Home}/{test1}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Genric", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Test2",
    url: "{Home}/{test2}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Genric", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```